Почему при использовании proxy_pass не добавляется заголовок в ответ с помощью add_header NGINX?
Сделал маршрут в конфигурации nginx ниже.
location /test-route/ {
    add_header Custom-Host $host;
    add_header 'Host' '$host:8080';
    
    # Вариант 1
    # proxy_set_header Host $host:8080;
    # proxy_pass http://servers;
    
    # Вариант 2
    # return 200 'success';
}

Можете подсказать, почему при выполнении курла на nginx сервер с первым вариантом в ответе на запрос нет заголовка Custom-Host? А во втором варианте есть.
add_header ведь добавляет заголовок уже в ответ? Почему при использовании proxy_pass его нет?
Сам запрос тоже не содержит каких-то особенных заголовков.
curl -v --location 'server-one.ru/test-route/main' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{"amount":1}'

Ответ.
* Host server-one.ru:8080 was resolved.
* IPv6: (none)
* IPv4: 
* Connected to server-one.ru port 8080
> POST /test-route/main HTTP/1.1
> Host: server-one.ru:8080
> User-Agent: curl/8.6.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 57
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 
< Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
< Date: Sun, 01 Sep 2024 06:36:36 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Vary: Origin
< Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
< Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 0
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self'
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
< 
* Leftovers after chunking: 5 bytes
* Connection #0 to host server-one.ru left intact
{"respose": "body"}


А какой ответ возвращает бекенд? add_header по умолчанию не добавляет ничего для ошибочных ответов (>= 400)

@AlexeyTen если проверять напрямую вызвав один из серверов в upstream servers, то успешный ответ с 200 кодом. А если через nginx, то тоже 200, но без заголовка.

покажите вывод curl -v ...

@AlexeyTen да, добавил в вопрос

Что-то у вас запрос и лог не сходятся. В логе используется порт 8080, а nginx судя по описанию слушает порт 80. Ну и «Content-Length: 57» намекает что это не '{"amount":1}
Так что давайте ещё раз и настоящий запрос и ответ целиком.

И уберите параметр --location.
